# react native app or expo not working on virtual device after ejecting showing error

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

the project runs on expo mobile device but not runs on android emulator 
so i have run below command
after running

```
npm run eject
```

or

```
expo eject
```

it displays me the following errors I have tried all possible ways even updated
babel-preset, react-native-scripts to 2. something
but it does n't works

```
> react-native run-android

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\rcf\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\local
-cli\cliEntry.js:11:41)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Module._compile (D:\rcf\AwesomeProject\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:
83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\rcf\AwesomeProject\node_modules\pirates\lib
\index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to install this two dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core
npm install --save-dev @babel/runtime
```

Comment: getting below errors after adding this dependencies Could not find the "expo" package in your project when configuring the packager
`Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug)...
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html`

Comment: your devices is not connected or your emulator is not running, check "adb devices" to check running devices

Comment: adb device running perfectly have compiled my another android studio project

Comment: have you set the ANDROID_HOME environtment?

Comment: Yes I have set My environtment ANDROID_HOME

Comment: see this https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/255#issuecomment-453214632

Comment: It gives me following error after resolving the expo package  `> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
D:\rnp\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\aaa\MainApplication.java:5:
` refer above image